# session not created exception from disconnected unable to connect to renderer katalon

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automation, katalon-studio

I am having an issue with chrome running on katalon on a windows 7 machine. When it opens chrome it just gets stuck with data; in the address bar. I have scoured the internet for answers, Tried updating the chrome drivers, updating chrome, updating selenium but they all seem to get stuck on opening chrome.

Below is the log from katalon

> Test Case FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: 'GlobalVariable.URLQA' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created
>   from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
>     (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 7.84 seconds
>   Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
>   System info: host: 'Removed', ip: ''Removed', ', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>   Driver info: driver.version: CChromeDriver)

Some information has been removed from that log for privacy reasons.

Additional information:

The script always seems to get as far as creating the new chrome driver and then stopping. It crashes the same without this code it just pops up that extensions have been disabled by the administrator first.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe")

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)
```

My chrome is version 72 and I have tried both the 72 chrome driver seen above and the 2.46 chromedriver.

Comment: it's trying to open a URL named "GlobalVariable.URLQA" .... that's obviously not a valid URL.  remove the quotes to make it a variable.

Comment: That's a Katalon global variable, it has a URL defined in it so it's not that, and just to be sure I tried manually putting the address in and it gave the same output.

Comment: it's name is being passed to webdriver as a string as the log shows.

Comment: Test Case FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: 'www.google.com' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer

Comment: It isn't to do with the URL, it crashes no matter what URL you use. It is crashing when it opens chrome